# pluck con condicional

Tags: laravel

estoy haciendo mis pinitos en Laravel y migrando una aplicación de Control Horario hecha originariamente en PHP.

El caso es que he creado un CRUD con Crud Generator pero en la tabla donde muestra los datos quiero que coja datos de otra tabla al estilo INNER_JOIN con pluck cuando se cumpla una condición.

En la tabla ASISTENCIA tengo un campo codigo_persona que deberia mostrarme unos datos cuando coincida con la fila de EMPLEADOS con coincidencia en el campo codigo_empleado.

Este es el código que tengo ahora pero peta por todas partes y me he quedado bloqueado. Any idea?

```
public function index()
{
    $asistencias = Asistencia::paginate();
     $empleados = Empleado::where('codigo_empleado','asistencias.codigo_empleado')->pluck('nombre','apellidos');

    return view('asistencia.index', compact('asistencias','empleados'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * $asistencias->perPage());
}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: He modificado el código anterior y ya no devuelve errores pero no me muestra los campos nombre y apellidos de la otra tabla en la vista...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos por la consulta en esta parte.

```
$asistencias = Asistencias::paginate();
```

Esta consulta nos devuelve una paginación que podría servirte para hacerla en la vista pero NO en una consulta

Por otra parte.

```
$empleados = Empleado::where('codigo_empleado','asistencias.codigo_empleado')->pluck('nombre','apellidos');
```

El uso del query builder en la clausula where la documentación nos dicta que debemos pasar como primer argumento la columna de la tabla, seguido del operador y por ultimo el valor con el que se debe hacer la comparación.
Quedando como:

```
$empleados = Empleado::where('codigo_empleado',$codigo_empleado)->get(['nombre','apellidos']);
//Aqui estoy omitiendo el segundo argumento porque estoy dando por entendido que debe ser = (igual) a la variable $codigo_empleado y al usar el metodo get seguido de el arreglo con las tablas que necesito unicamente de esa peticion para amortiguar tiempo de ejecucion
```

Si todo esta bien modelado en tu base de datos y en los modelos tienes las relacion que laravel te provee podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
Empleado::whereHas('asistencia')->get();
```

Esto para obtener los empleados que tengan una asistencia registrada en tu base de datos y, si requires usar condicionales dentro de esa relacion puedes pasar na funcion anonima a al metodo whereHas.

```
Empleado::whereHas('asistencia', function($query){
    $query->where('asistencia', 1);
})->get();
```

Si tienes dudas acá esta la [documentacion](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses) de laravel

Comment: Gracias Julito, finalmente lo he solventado relacionando las tablas con una clave foránea.

Comment: Por nada. Si te ha servido te agradeceria si marcas la respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Sin problema, gracias de nuevo